# Custom Post Types, slug, archive and SEO plugins

Tags: posts, slug, seo, customization

I made a custom post type called "friends".

I am able to correctly list my friends using this urls:

```
http://mysite/friends/friend1/

http://mysite/friends/friend2/

http://mysite/friends/friend3/
```

But I have a "logic" problem with the "archive page"

My problem is:

If I use the "has_archive" option of my custom field I am able to see  my page but I am not able to use SEO plugins to improve my page in term of searchability and I am not able to put some content inside the page before the while ( have_posts() )  statement using "the_content" statement I would normally use in a page template.

If I try to use a Page with the slug /slugfriends/ I am able to use SEO plugins, I can even write some content and I can then use query_posts to cycle through my friends but it seems that there is no possibility to have the same slug reserved for my custom post type. So i seems that I can have:

```
http://mysite/slugfriends/ (served by my page)

http://mysite/friends/friend1/ (served buy custom post type)

http://mysite/friends/friend2/
```

but I can't have:

```
http://mysite/friends/ (served by my page)

http://mysite/friends/friend1/ (served buy custom post type)

http://mysite/friends/friend2/
```

Is there anyone that has reached the goal to have such configuration running? Maybe using some  hooks or similar? I tried in many ways but no one seems to work.

Regards,
Marcello

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what content you want to insert in your archive page, but you can always use the file "archive-friends.php" as you can see in the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)  to loop your "friends" post type.

Then, to customize the SEO, I recommend you the plugin [WordPress SEO by Yoast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) because it has a strong compatibility with custom post types, so that you will be able to define your SEO description and titles for your "friends".